# Databinding in asp.net using placeholder

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp-classic

I need to put a table in the div which contains textboxs and labels when someone click on a button.

Structure of table is as below...

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label id="l1" text="adfa"></label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="t1">
</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

The no of rows can vary but the structure of a row will be same as here in the above table.

I am trying to use Placeholder but confused how to put all the stuff their...

Comment: You need a data control like a repeater or a gridview

Comment: Do u want to do this using javascript or serverside event? Looks like server side, but just to be sure

Comment: ASP.NET or ASP classic? Do you need to create the table dynamically or is it possible to simply switch visibility of it?

Comment: i could have use visibility but the no of rows might be 2 or 200....so can't use visibility..

Comment: Do you want the whole table to switch visibility or just specific rows?

Comment: @arrestwarrant: You can set the PlaceHolder's `Visible` property if you want to show all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < noofsubject; i++)
        {
            table.Width = 760;
            TableRow tRow1 = new TableRow();
            TableCell tCell11 = new TableCell();
            tCell11.Text = "Subject " + i;
            tRow1.Cells.Add(tCell11);
            table.Rows.Add(tRow1);
        }
  PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table);
```

I was looking for this..

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing this operation client-side or server-side (for the latter, are you posting back to the server to update the response)?  If the latter, using a ListView control would work perfectly, as you can define it as:

```
<asp:ListVIew .. ItemPlaceholderID="Items">
   <LayoutTemplate>
       <table>
           <tr runat="server" id="Items" />
       </table>
   </LayoutTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
     <tr>
<td>
<label id="l1" text="afda"></label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="t1">
</td>
</tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Then you can do:

```
ListView1.DataSource = //some data source
ListView1.DataBind()
```

The data can be empty rows just to populate the list initially, or some valid data.  Some further references:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790(v=vs.100).aspx